# GREP a range of files with a numeric filename

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have files that are located in a temp folder that I need to move to another folder, the files are named in sequence as so:

```
1_492724_860619121.dbf.gz
1_492725_860619121.dbf.gz
1_492726_860619121.dbf.gz
...
1_493069_860619121.dbf.gz
```

I used to move these files monthly so I used grep on the month in question :

```
for i in `ls -ltr | grep Jul|awk '{print $9}'`; do mv $i JulFolder; done
```

Now I only want to move a range of files based on their name :
from `1_492724_860619121.dbf.gz` to `1_493053_860619121.dbf.gz`

What is the correct use the of combination of `grep` and `awk` to select the desired files ?

**Note** that `awk '{print $9}'` is used to select the right column containing the files' name from `ls -ltr`.

Comment: You have to define what you mean by **range**. Do you man all the files with names in between the two you mentioned, with respect to the collating sequence of the current locale?

Comment: Regarding `What is the correct use the of combination of grep and awk` - there isn't one since you never need grep when you're using awk. For example, from the script in your question, `grep Jul|awk '{print $9}'` = `awk '/Jul/{print $9}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below.  (change FROM and TO as you want)

```
for i in `ls -1|awk -F_ '{if($2 >= FROM && $2 <= TO) print $0}' FROM=492724 TO=493053`
do 
    mv $i toFolder
done
```

Comment: Do not, ever, never parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: ... and do always quote your variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes (and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about some of the issues with it.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try with a bash range?

```bash
mv 1_{492724..493053}_860619121.dbf.gz somefolder/
```

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with plain POSIX-shell grammar:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

min=492724
max=493053
src_dir=./
dst_dir=~/somewhere
mkdir -p "$dst_dir"

# Iterates path in src_dir matching the pattern
for path in "$src_dir"/1_*_*.dbf.gz; do

  # Trims out leading directory and 1_ prefix from path
  file_part=${path##*/1_}

  # Trims out trailing _* from file_part to keep only number
  number=${file_part%%_*}

  # Checks number is within desired range
  if [ "$number" -ge "$min" ] && [ "$number" -le "$max" ]; then
    # Moves the file
    mv -- "$path" "$dst_dir/"
  fi
done
```